# Can't run terraform init after manully removed .terraform folder on Windows

Tags: terraform

I am having a problem with terraform init, and terrafor get. I wanted terraform to download my modules freshly so I removed .terraform folder. But when I tried terraform init, it always gave me something like:

Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'ssh://git@mygitaddr': C:\cygwin64\bin\git.exe exited with 128: fatal: could not create work tree dir '.terraform\modules\b58395849f04859395839': No such file or directory.

It seems like terraform is still looking for my old module. I have spent some time searching online and suspect that this is somehow related to symlink but I'm not sure. However, it had no problem running in intellij with same setup using Run/Debug configurations. It also worked in windows cmd prompt.

I'm using terraform 0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the following steps.

1.) start Cygwin terminal and go to your git/terraform project:

```
$ cd git/<PROJECT>/<FOLDER with FILES.tf>
```

2.) now create terraform-folder and subfolder:

```
$ mkdir -p .terraform/modules/
```

3.) execute:

```
$ terraform get
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized that the it was my cygwin that caused the problem. My cygwin was using its own git tool and it was trying to find the git files within cygwin system path, of course it couldn't find them. So I had to uninstall cygwin git tool and made it use the one on my system, and it worked.